# How to make a draggable carousel with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel with JavaScript.

I want to have 5 slides to show by default. then we can use the left and right arrows to slide the next and back.

I cannot find any resources to learn this.

Can some give me an idea of how I should do this?

I am not asking for a solution. I just want the idea to run by myself to learn it.

```css
#home-b .listing-carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-track-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f40c43;
  height: 100%;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.45rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-btn-left {
  left: -3rem;
}

#home-b .listing-carousel .carousel-btn-right {
  right: -3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing-carousel mx-auto text-center">
  <button class="carousel-btn carousel-btn-left">
    <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="carousel-track-container">
    <ul class="carousel-track">
      <li class="carousel-slide">
        <img
          class="carousel-image"
          src="assets/img/featured-1.png"
          alt="featured-listing-1"
        />
      </li>
      <li class="carousel-slide">
        <img
          class="carousel-image"
          src="assets/img/featured-2.png"
          alt="featured-listing-2"
        />
      </li>
      <li class="carousel-slide">
        <img
          class="carousel-image"
          src="assets/img/featured-3.png"
          alt="featured-listing-3"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-btn carousel-btn-right">
    <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways doing this. I suggest you to read this https://www.cssscript.com/draggable-touch-slider-carousel/ if you want to build it from scratch. If you don't want to bother I suggest you use Swiper library, it's fairly simple and a really good library.

Comment: @bluebird Thank you for the resource. So I just change the width to show multiple items at a time right?

Comment: Yes but not only, it needs some fine tuning in JS from what I have tested, you have to reset the left position earlier than if you keep just one slide at a time.
Also, check this : https://swiperjs.com/demos/#multiple_slides_per_view